# How to split this polynomal?

Tags: polynomials

Let
$$P(x) = \frac{x}{(x+3)(x+2)} = \frac{3}{x+3} - \frac{2}{x+2}$$

I can verify it's true, but I'm not sure how they came up with exactly this polynomal splitting.

Can you please help?

Comment: Are you familiar with [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)?

Comment: @HDE226868 Probably not :) That's why I've asked this question. That seemed very basic, and that's why I found no solutions for this in my textbooks.

Comment: Okay; you've got a good answer so far from Aniket to make up for the textbooks, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{x}{(x+3)(x+2)} = \frac{A}{x+3} + \frac{B}{x+2}$$

i.e. $$x=A(x+2)+B(x+3)$$ which is an identity in $x$.

Now solve for $A$ and $B$ to get the above relation.

Comment: You can even do it faster (if I may suggest) : use $x=-2$ and then $x=-3$ in the equation. Small trick from a lazy old man ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici good one..:-)

Comment: This is a very classical way to do it ! Use it and just get the values without solving (almost) any equation. Cheers :-)